# JSP - How to add a new class to an HTML element without losing the old attribute value?

Tags: html, css, class, jsp

i have an HTML form where almost all'input elements have already a class and I need to add a new one dynamically with JSP.

Now the question is that if I simply do: class = "newClass" the old value would be lost, and I'm not able to do something like class += " newClass". 
So how can I add a new class, depending to the response of a servlet, to an HTML element with JSP without losing the previous value.

This is the code:

```
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" class = "main-class"
<%if (request.getAttribute("name") != null) {%> class = "error"    <%}%>placeholder="Nome" value="<%=request.getParameter("name") != null ?  request.getParameter("name") : ""%>" />
```

`

Answer (score 2):

I think extract one Java variable would work for you.
Here is the code:

```
<%
   String classList = "main-class";
   if (request.getAttribute("name") != null) {
     classList += "error";
   }
%>
<input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="<%=classList%>" />
```

Just skip the placeholder and value attribute.